# Why do I get multiple tsc processes running under WebStorm?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

Every time I save a .ts file, I see "7 processes running" in the status bar, which take around 30s to complete. If I "ps" the tsc processes, I can see 7 `tsc --sourcemap xxx.ts` for 7 of my .ts files from a corpus of around 30. It's always the same 7, and they have no obvious relationship to the specific .ts file I'm working on.

My watcher settings seem pretty unremarkable  ...

[image]

Comment: File Watchers start a separate external process (in this case TypeScript compiler) for each changed file. So the number of processes spawned are related to the number of .ts files referencing the modified file. BTW, try clearing "Track only root files" option - does it make any difference?

Comment: What do you mean by "referencing"? The tsc compilations that are spawned don't reference the current file directly (some, but not all, do indirectly). Did you mean "Compile main files only"?  I unchecked that and I now get the behaviour I expected, ie. just compile the current file. Feel free to post that as an answer (ideally with an explanation as it seems counterintuitive) so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "Compile main files only" option is enabled, watchers are run for all files that reference the original file directly or indirectly, via `///<reference>`tags or imports, spawning a separate external process for each of them. Disabling this option results in compiling the current file only

Note that it's recommended to enable this option when running tsc with `-out` parameter